# jquery issue in custom module magento 2

Tags: magento2, javascript, jquery, requirejs

i am on the way to create a custom module for sliding. But always its driving me crazy on jquery issues. Sometime the js will load and everything will be fine. After sometime, jquery wont get loaded.

```
var config = {
map: {
    '*': {
             'flexslider': 'Slidermodule_Mymodule/js/jquery.flexslider-min'
    }
} };
```

and the script looks like

```
require([ 'jquery', 'flexslider', 'domReady!'], function(){   jQuery(document).ready(function () {
jQuery('.flexslider').flexslider();  });  });
```

Some time there is no error. Sometime there is error on refresh. Please advise.

Answer (score 2):

The flexslider plugin doesn't use an AMD pattern, so you'll have to use a 'shim' to guarantee jQuery as a dependency.

Take a look at Alan Storm's excellent article, he has a whole section dedication to "*RequireJS and jQuery Plugins*":
[Alan Storm: Magento 2 and RequireJS](http://alanstorm.com/magento_2_and_requirejs)